# XML Read throws "device not ready"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xml, iis

I'm trying to read a xml file but everytime the code arrives at the load()-function it throws the exeption "the device is not ready". This is the code:

```
const string filepath = @"E:\xml\somefile.xml";
XmlDocument fileDoc = new XmlDocument();
fileDoc.Load(filepath);
```

The drive "E:\" is a physical HDD where the webapplication is saved in a folder called "app". So the folder xml is completely independent of the web apllication and iis. I also tried to locate the xml in the application folder but the same error occured.

Has someone an idea what I am missing?

Comment: No, working correctly. The application is also saved on that hard drive and everything works fine except the xml.load()

Comment: Check the access rights for the webapp's user.

Comment: acces rights are set to 'everyone' has full access (read, wirte, open)

Answer (score 1):

Check if the file "E:\xml\somefile.xml" is not locked in you process when you try to read the xml. Use the right usinging of call Dispose() on the objects which write the file.

Comment: In the computermanagement I can't see that the file is opened by someone. It is a non-changeing file. It only stores data and noone / no function ever writes into it. It gets only accessed once by code an this time the error occures... :(